# Word request : The property of being aesthetic

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm comparing visual query languages (visual computer languages used for querying databases). Criteria include conciseness (the fewness of words needed to express queries), expressive power (the richness of the queries that can be expressed), etc.

I'm looking for a name for a (hopefully one-word) criterion that describes the "aestheticness" (the "appealness") of a language (the quality of queries being visually appealing).

Comment: Do you want the name of the scale or points on the scale? appeal, beauty, aesthetics, expressibility

Comment: I don't consider the criteria as scales because they are more qualitative than quantitative.

Comment: oh sure, words aren't always on a continuum but  usually there's a name for two opposites together: light or heavy is weight. Sometimes the scale is the name of one end: hungry or full is hunger.

Comment: "Aesthetics" is the word I currently use. I was hoping for some "-ness" word (the quality of being...)

Comment: Perhaps, [_attractiveness_](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/attractiveness)?

Answer (score 1):

My first thought is ***attractiveness***:

> ***[Attractiveness](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/attractiveness)***
>
> NOUN
>
> 1. The quality of being pleasing or appealing to the senses.
>      *‘this scheme could enhance the attractiveness of the area’*
>
>    1.1 (in a person) the quality of being appealing or sexually alluring to look at.
>      *‘my aunt did not marry until late in life in spite of her attractiveness’*
>      _‘simply smiling can increase your attractiveness to others’
>
>    1.2 The possession of qualities or features that arouse interest.
>      *‘the new agreements will enhance the city 's attractiveness to overseas
>      investors’*

You could just go with its ***appeal***:

> ***[Appeal](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/appeal)***
>
> NOUN
>
> 4. mass noun The quality of being attractive or interesting.
>      *‘the popular appeal of football’*

Or you could speak of its ***allure***:

> ***[Allure](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/allure)***
>
> NOUN
>
> *[mass noun]*
>
> The quality of being powerfully and mysteriously attractive or
>   fascinating.
>   *‘people for whom gold holds no allure’*

Answer (score 0):

If you really want a one-word term for this, why not the Greek compound **call(e)iconography**, which is in my opinion the perfect word to describe *the "aestheticness" (the "appealness") of a language (the quality of queries being visually appealing).*

The Greek words I've used for this compound are:

1. [καλός](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CE%BA%CE%B1%CE%BB%CF%8C%CF%82).
2. [εἰκών](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CE%B5%E1%BC%B0%CE%BA%CF%8E%CE%BD).
3. [γράφω](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CE%B3%CF%81%CE%AC%CF%86%CF%89).

I know it's a very rare word, if not made up by me on the spot, but weren't all these learned words equally non-existent before someone brought them into lexical being?

Answer (score -1):

"[Elegant](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/elegance)" is a word that I have seen refer to things like scientific theories and experiments, but also programming languages.